# How can I make Sql Server Management Studio syntax highlight in the same colors as visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a custom color scheme for VS from studiostyle.info.
How can I make ssms respect it so that my queries are nice and white on black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this: http://winterdom.com/2007/10/colorschemesinsql2005managementstudio

You might need to modify it slightly depending on the version of VS and SMS you run. It works perfectly with VS2k10 and SQL SMS 2k8

Answer (score 2):

Just import a style file from http://studiostyl.es ....

1. Tool>Import and Export Settings>Import>next>yes>next>Browse
2. Find your file.
3. Select it in list.
4. Hit next>finish.

And now you have a custom color scheme.

If you want to import your Visual Studio color scheme, do the same thing in VS but export only your text and fonts. You can then import them into SSMS just the same ways as above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, didn't know importing VS Settings into SSMS worked. Just tried importing the theme I use in VS 2010, into SSMS 2012 and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in SQL follow this guide [How to: Change Font Color, Size, and Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173754.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

And for an old-skhool method if you are languishing back on 2008 R2 at a corporate client:

- Tools

  - Options
  - Environment

    - Font and Colors
    - Text Editor

Here are my custom colo(u)rs for a Darcula style theme in SSMS:

`Background: 43 43 43 or #2B2B2B
Foreground: 169 183 198 #A9B7C6
Keyword: 204 120 50 #CC7832
Line Comment: 128 128 128 #808080
Sql String:  106 135 89 #6A8759`